# My letsencrypt is expiring. How do I renew it via the command line?

Tags: command-line-interface, lets-encrypt

I am on ubuntu 14 and I just got an email saying my letsencrypt is expiring soon. How do I go about renewing this via the command line?

I tried running the command **./letsencrypt-auto renew** but that doesnt do anything.

My letsencrypt folder is located in /etc/letsencrypt and I only have one site hosted.

Comment: How do you know it doesn't do anything? Did you check the certificate to see if it was renewed? Did you check the logs for the let's encrypt software to see if it reported any errors?

Comment: still need to restart the service if you didn't specify a post-hook.